# Library for displaying image sets on an iPad

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, image, ipad

I'm looking for some cool libraries out there to display a bunch of images in my iPad application.

I think they are already out there, and I don't have to start from scratch, but I can't find some good ones.

Comment: don't you mean start from nil?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [KTPhotoBrowser](https://github.com/kirbyt/KTPhotoBrowser), I use it in a universal app, and it works pretty good.

Also, search [Github : Photo Gallery](https://github.com/search?type=Everything&language=objective-c&q=photo+gallery&repo=&langOverride=&x=0&y=0&start_value=1) for more open-source solutions.

Comment: KTPhotoBrowser looks really good. looks like it also can be used on an iPad. Will check that out tonight.

Comment: As I have stated, I use it in my universal app, so yes, it works great on the iPad too.

Answer (score 3):

Check out [AQGridView](https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/AQGridView) as well.

Answer (score 0):

See the answers to these questions on Stack Overflow:

- [How To Create A Gallery on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3866766/how-to-create-a-gallery-on-ios)
- [float:left in objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4649330/floatleft-in-objective-c)

There are probably more questions about the same subject. Seek and you shall find.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply create a web page with all the images, and then display it using UIWebView.

Answer (score 0):

Did you want to do the coding yourself?

I found the Apple example ["LazyTableImages"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html) to be a useful and elegant way to display many images in a table view. It's important to a) keep the scrolling nice and smooth, and b) not freeze the user interface while downloading.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using a [UIImageView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)?

Comment: shure. but i dont only want to display a single image. i need something to diplay a lot of images. probably something like the appstore uses or a "popup" controller for images